Simply split data into groups so they can be operated on
So, I frequently run into a situation where I have to partition or group data (logically) and then compare them. Something like:
"How often was a value in the group and not in the group and what was their respective percentages"
select LESS_THAN, GREATER_THAN, round(LESS_THAN /(LESS_THAN+GREATER_THAN),4) as percentage
from (
    select 'less than' as type, level as rn from dual where level <= 5  connect by level <= 10 union
    select 'greater than' as type, level as rn from dual where level > 5 connect by level <= 10
)
pivot(
    sum(rn)
    for type in (
        'less than' as LESS_THAN, 'greater than' as GREATER_THAN
    )
);

Is there some clever way to simplify this sort of thing?

SUM(CASE WHEN level <= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  less_than

Please provide a complete [,mre] with sample data and desired results.

Since you asked for undefined general way of manipulating the data in a way similar to excel - there is a MODEL clause in Oracle sql that could do pretty much anything as excel. It alows you to address and manipulate the data like in an excel sheet.
MODEL clause looks a bit tricky at first  but it is very fast, mighty and reliable with complex data manipulations. Here is a small example:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl AS
Select  1 as ID, 'A' as CATEGORY,  13 as QUANTITY From Dual Union All
Select  2,       'A',              13 From Dual Union All
Select  3,       'A',              15 From Dual Union All
Select  4,       'A',              13 From Dual Union All
Select  5,       'A',              14 From Dual Union All
Select  6,       'A',              15 From Dual Union All
Select  7,       'A',              17 From Dual Union All
Select  8,       'B',              15 From Dual Union All
Select  9,       'B',              17 From Dual Union All
Select 10,       'B',              21 From Dual;

--      S Q L :  
Select   ID, CATEGORY, QUANTITY,
         COUNT_PER_CAT, 
         is_unique_per_cat,
         Count(Distinct Case When is_unique_per_cat = 1 Then QUANTITY End) Over(Partition By CATEGORY) as count_unique_quantities, 
         avg_per_cat, 
         is_lesser_then_avg, 
         Count(Case When is_lesser_then_avg = 1 Then 1 End) Over(Partition By CATEGORY) as count_lesser, 
         is_greater_then_avg, 
         Count(Case When is_greater_then_avg = 1 Then 1 End) Over(Partition By CATEGORY) as count_greater,
         pct_count_lesser,
         pct_count_greater
FROM 
  ( Select * From  tbl 
    --      M O D E L    C l a u s e :
    MODEL   Dimension By   ( ID, CATEGORY )
            Measures  (  QUANTITY, 
                         --
                         0 as count_per_cat,
                         0 as is_unique_per_cat,
                         --
                         0.0 as avg_per_cat, 
                         0 as is_lesser_then_avg, 
                         0 as is_greater_then_avg, 
                         --
                         0.0 as pct_count_lesser,
                         0.0 as pct_count_greater
                      )
         RULES ( count_per_cat[ANY, CATEGORY] = COUNT(*)[ANY, CATEGORY = CV(CATEGORY)], 
                 is_unique_per_CAT[ANY, CATEGORY] = Case When Count(Distinct CATEGORY) Over( Partition By QUANTITY[CV(), CV()]) = 1 Then 1 End,
                 --
                 avg_per_cat[ANY, CATEGORY] = Round(AVG(QUANTITY)[ANY, CV()], 2),
                 is_lesser_then_avg[ANY, CATEGORY] = Case When QUANTITY[CV(), CV()] < avg_per_cat[CV(), CV()] Then 1 End,
                 is_greater_then_avg[ANY, CATEGORY] = Case When QUANTITY[CV(), CV()] > avg_per_cat[CV(), CV()] Then 1 End,
                 ---
                 pct_count_lesser[ANY, CATEGORY] = Round(Count(is_lesser_then_avg)[ANY, CV()] * 100 / Count(*)[ANY, CV()], 2), 
                 pct_count_greater[ANY, CATEGORY] = Round(Count(is_greater_then_avg)[ANY, CV()] * 100 / Count(*)[ANY, CV()], 2)
               )
  )
ORDER BY ID

R e s u l t :



ID
CATEGORY
QUANTITY
COUNT_PER_CAT
IS_UNIQUE_PER_CAT
COUNT_UNIQUE_QUANTITIES
AVG_PER_CAT
IS_LESSER_THEN_AVG
COUNT_LESSER
IS_GREATER_THEN_AVG
COUNT_GREATER
PCT_COUNT_LESSER
PCT_COUNT_GREATER




1
A
13
7
1
2
14.29
1
4
null
3
57.14
42.86


2
A
13
7
1
2
14.29
1
4
null
3
57.14
42.86


3
A
15
7
null
2
14.29
null
4
1
3
57.14
42.86


4
A
13
7
1
2
14.29
1
4
null
3
57.14
42.86


5
A
14
7
1
2
14.29
1
4
null
3
57.14
42.86


6
A
15
7
null
2
14.29
null
4
1
3
57.14
42.86


7
A
17
7
null
2
14.29
null
4
1
3
57.14
42.86


8
B
15
3
null
1
17.67
1
2
null
1
66.67
33.33


9
B
17
3
null
1
17.67
1
2
null
1
66.67
33.33


10
B
21
3
1
1
17.67
null
2
1
1
66.67
33.33



fiddle

You can use conditional aggregation to replicate your logic in a single query:
SELECT SUM(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN rn END) AS less_than,
       SUM(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN NULL ELSE rn END) AS not_less_than,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN rn ELSE 0 END) / SUM(rn), 4) AS less_than_percent,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN 0 ELSE rn END) / SUM(rn), 4) AS not_less_than_percent
FROM   table_name

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (type, rn) AS
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN level <= 4
         THEN 'less than'
         ELSE 'greater than'
         END,
         level
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

Outputs:



LESS_THAN
NOT_LESS_THAN
LESS_THAN_PERCENT
NOT_LESS_THAN_PERCENT




10
45
.1818
.8182




However, if the question is:

How often was a value in the group and not in the group and what was their respective percentages

Use COUNT and AVG rather than SUM:
SELECT COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN 1 END) AS less_than,
       COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS not_less_than,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END), 4) AS less_than_percent,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE type WHEN 'less than' THEN 0 ELSE 100 END), 4) AS not_less_than_percent
FROM   table_name

Which outputs:



LESS_THAN
NOT_LESS_THAN
LESS_THAN_PERCENT
NOT_LESS_THAN_PERCENT




4
6
40
60



fiddle

I meant this more as a general question. I am routinely trying to compare groups where they bifurcate logically, as above. Should I update the question to be clearer?

@ChristianBongiorno Updated.
